# Can I have/chain more than 1 _Layout pages in MVC 3? for a cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a layout page and some pages that use it. But I want to implement a navigation control on some of the sub-pages that use it. So I want to use another nested layout page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it works great.  Just tell your layout page to use another layout page

```
@{ Layout = "pathToMyOtherLayout"; }
```

You can also use sections to pass through to the parent layouts.  For example:

```
@Section Headers {@RenderSection("Headers")}
```

Comment: The detail for passing through Sections was what I needed - thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can chain pages just like you can Master Pages, in _ViewStart.cshtml you will see how the layout page is defined:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

You can just add this section in the _Layout.cshtml to reference another parent, or add it to an individual view to reference a different layout view.

ScottGu has a post with more info on [Razor Layouts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)

I use this exact method for what you are talking about on some ecommerce sites, where you are in the checkout process I do not want any distractions (navigation, etc) within the view, so instead of having some special case `if checkout` in layout, I make a `LayoutBrandingOnly` and a `Layout` which "inherits" from it so I don't have to repeat all the branding html.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this easily enough in one layout page by using sections.
check http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: This is ok when you don't mind repeating the overriding of navigation on a bunch of views to blank.  But if you have an entire folder of views that need a subtly different layout, using layout "inheritance" is a bit cleaner, helps you to not repeat yourself.

Comment: I agree that inheritance would be cleaner in large projects but either way you will be having to maintain something in the view that denotes it as being different than the average view. Overriding navigation permissions can be a little more informative of what is actually happening different in a view than using multiple levels of inheritance, unless you use very descriptive long names to define your layouts so you can convey that information at a glance without having to track back up the inheritance chain.