# How to inherit more rendersection in mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Well, hello every body, I started with mvc4, I don't known how to inherit one View from more RenderSection. Such as PageMain inheritance _Layout, then SubMain1 inheritance PageMain. View my code snippet.

```
_Layout.cshtml

<body>
This is layout
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("Main",required: false)
</body>


PageMain.cshtml inherit from _Layout

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
This is PageMain
@section Main{
    This is Main
}
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("SubMain1",required: false)
@RenderSection("SubMain2",required: false)


SubMain1.cshtml inherit from PageMain

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/PageABC/PageMain.cshtml";
}
This is SubMain1
@section Main{
    This is Main in page SubMain
}
@section SubMain1{
    This is SubMain1
}
@section SubMain2{
    This is SubMain2
}
```

When i try it, I get error `cannot be requested directly because it calls the “RenderSection” method` . Can you tell me what the mistake in here and give me adviced for this ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try maybe add section inside PageMain, something like this `@section Main{
    @RenderSection("SubMain",required: false)
    This is Main
}`

Comment: Hi #Sousuke , I try it, SubMain1.cshtml is ok , but PageMain.cshtml is not ok, It just get error `The file "~/Views/Home/PageMain.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the “RenderSection” method`

Comment: You have to load PageMain as section? Maybe try use partial view instead. What you are trying to achive with this structure? Maybe there is other way

Comment: Yes , as say above, PageMain as section, it's inherit from _Layout , then i create SubMain1 as section and it's inherit from PageMain . Can i use it ? SubMain inheritance from more view (_Layout and PageMain)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960216/can-i-have-chain-more-than-1-layout-pages-in-mvc-3-for-a-cshtml-page

Comment: I've tried everything, but seems not working, It still above error @@.

Comment: Anybody known about this ?